# impression on somebody

Tags: word-usage

If I saw an attractive girl, then I thought her long time. That is

> I left deep impression on her.

Or

> She left deep impression on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**To leave an impression on you**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+an+impression) or [**to leave you with an impression**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+an+impression) means that you are the one who is left impressed and not the other person. Since it is you who were left impressed and spent days thinking about the girl, the deep impression you're talking about in your two sentences must have been left on you. In other words, you were the receiver of the impression and not the other way around. Therefore, it should be the second sentence:

> She left a deep impression on me.

And please don't forget to precede "deep impression" with an indefinite article because in this case "impression" is a countable noun.